# Rounded Ends on Circular Graph? iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, graph, charts

I am trying to reproduce the rounded ends on the circular graph it is not working out for myself.

I tried google and cannot find the exact terminology to recreate it.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction or tell me what I am looking for ?

I want a circular graph that looks like so

https://www.punchkickinteractive.com/content/uploads/2014/10/apple-watch-activity-app.jpeg

If there is an assisting library that I can style that would even be better

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what kind of difficulties do you have any? If just with drawing, so there is one way:

```
@interface ArcView ()

@property (nonatomic) double arcAngel;

@end

@implementation ArcView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2);
    double lineWidth = 10;
    double radius = center.x - lineWidth / 2;

    UIBezierPath *backCircle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                              radius:radius
                                                          startAngle:0
                                                            endAngle:2 * M_PI
                                                           clockwise:YES];
    backCircle.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    backCircle.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:1.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.3f] setStroke];
    [backCircle stroke];

    UIBezierPath *highlightCircle = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:center
                                                                   radius:radius
                                                               startAngle:-M_PI_2
                                                                 endAngle:self.arcAngel
                                                                clockwise:YES];
    highlightCircle.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    highlightCircle.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:1.0f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f] setStroke];
    [highlightCircle stroke];
}

- (void)updateCircle {
    self.arcAngel += M_PI_2;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

**UPD:** set `lineCapStyle` property to `kCGLineCapRound`

There is result:

[image]

Comment: I am unable to test the code right now but does the circular graph have rounded ends ? I am really bad with imagining these things

Comment: @George Host, oh no, it don't :) wait a minute i will update my answer